# PacketLoss in 2.4Ghz lead to latency issue in 5Ghz

Tags: wifi

Wifi router (N 600) emitting both 2.4ghz and 5ghz.
- due to interference in 2.4 ghz bandwidth, if the packet loss arises.
- does it lead to instability of its own hardware which ultimately lead to degrade of the signal quality for the devices connected to 5gh antenna.

Answer (score 0):

No. Issues in 2.4 GHz will not cause inferior service in 5GHz for a dual-band WiFi Router.
2.4 Ghz and 5Ghz can be considered as two independent pipes going to the Wifi-router. They are two independent radios and use different frequencies, so they wont interfear at all.

If you are experiencing a problem in 5 GHz, I suggest you to change the 5 GHz channel used. There are many smart-phone applicaitons that helps to scan for wifi signals.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

-- While my wifi router(disable with 5Ghz) was facing the problem with interference on 2.4Ghz band width, with huge packet loss, i was trying to change its channel, but could not log into !
--While trying to open its admin page it was not loading. 
--I started to ping its ip from Wired connection , there i could realize its showing a huge packet loss. 
-- Iam afraid if i enable the 5Ghz bandwidth , the issue due to 2.4Ghz packetloss will effect the devices connected to the same hardware via 5Ghz band width !!